# How can I avoid customer to log in twice, in different browsers/computers?

Tags: magento-1.9, login, customer-session

I'm building an E-Learning system with Magento, and would like to avoid customer to share it's credentials with others. In other words, to avoid them to have multiple sessions with the same account.

The closest solution I've imagine, was saving sessions in DB (instead files), and add some `customer_id` column on `core_session` database, extending some core classes.

Is there an easier or better approach for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `log_visitor` and `log_visitor_online` tables.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Tim is a bit uncomplete but you need to have a look at these tables begin with `log_*`. It will permit you to know wether a customer is active on the website at the moment and details about the browser used to access it. Thanks to a link between `log_visitor_info` and `log_customer`.

Using that, you can call an observer to check if the user is already active. As far as I know, there is not a default solution.

Comment: I tried to see that table, but the log_visitor_online doesn't seem to be updated correctly. I've logged in with a customer, and in the table it still shows that the customer is a guest.

Comment: go to system > configuration > advanced > system. You'll see a tab "log" set to yes instead of "visitors only" or "no". That is what is probably set now.

Comment: Thank you, but didn't work either. log_visitor_online keeps with no record.

Comment: there is a refreshing rate under system > configuration> customers > customer configuration but I am on my phone and I am not sure of what it is.

Answer (score -2):

Not only is this hard to accomplish robustly, it will also degrade the experience for the customer. Imagine he's signed in at computer A (work) and forgot to log out, wants to log in at computer B (home) and finds out he still has an active session.

Comment: I do not think that was the point of the question. Moreover, you can set timeout for the session.

Comment: It's ok if I can invalidate the other session. I don't intend to avoid the customer login. I just don't want to allow multiple login.